# Upgrade facebook audience-network sdk Error?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-audience-network

I am Updating the facebook Audience Network SDK then Following Error Occurs.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>
> Could not resolve com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.32.0.
>   Required by:
>         project :app
>       Could not resolve com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.32.0.
>          Could not get resource 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/facebook/android/audience-network-sdk/4.32.0/audience-network-sdk-4.32.0.pom'.
>   Could not GET
>   'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/facebook/android/audience-network-sdk/4.32.0/audience-network-sdk-4.32.0.pom'.
>
> Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

How to Fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use 4.99.3 version, 4.32.0 doesn't exist. Make sure that you use Maven Central repo https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.facebook.android/audience-network-sdk/4.99.3/aar